# Between con campos null

Tags: sql, oracle

Buen día tengoo una tabla donde tengo que realizar una consulta between entre dos columnas de tipo date, el problema es que la columna de fecha fin puede tener datos null, existe alguna forma de realizar la consulta???

Aquí mi consulta

```
SELECT ACC INTO OUT_M1_PRIMNIV 
        FROM(SELECT ACC FROM T_M1_PRIMNIV 
        WHERE IN_APLICATIONDATE BETWEEN FECHA_INICIO AND FECHA_FIN AND
        (LINEA_NEGOCIO = IN_LINEA_NEG OR LINEA_NEGOCIO = '*') AND
        (ID_PRODUCTO = IN_ID_PROD OR ID_PRODUCTO = '*') AND 
        (ID_TARIFA = IN_ID_TARIFA OR ID_TARIFA = '*') AND
        (ID_CONVENIO = IN_ID_CONVENIO OR ID_CONVENIO = '*') AND
        (ID_VERSION = IN_ID_VER OR ID_VERSION = '*') AND
        (AGENCIA = IN_AGENCIA OR AGENCIA = '*') AND
        (CANAL_VENTA = IN_CANAL_VENTA OR CANAL_VENTA = '*') AND
        (SUBTIPO_DE_VEHICULO = F_SUBTIPO_VEHICULO OR SUBTIPO_DE_VEHICULO = '*') AND
        (CATEGORIA_DE_CIRCULACION = F_CAT_CIRC OR CATEGORIA_DE_CIRCULACION = '*') AND
        (GPOEST = F_GPO_EST OR GPOEST = '*') AND
        (CLAVE = IN_CLAVE OR CLAVE = '*') AND
        (MODELO = IN_MODELO OR MODELO = '*') AND
        (ESTADO = IN_ESTADO OR ESTADO = '*') AND
        (POBLACION = IN_POBLACION OR POBLACION = '*') AND
        (CP = IN_CP OR CP = '*') AND
        (GENERO = IN_GENERO OR GENERO = '*') AND
        (EDAD = IN_EDAD OR EDAD = '*') AND
        (USO = IN_USO OR USO = '*') ORDER BY ID)
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Lo que busco es que aunque la fecha fin sea null me devuelva el valor del campo solicitado en el select o dicho de otra forma que solo considere que el dato de fecha inicio sea menor al valor de application_date y que se consideren los demas criterios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lo que busco es que aunque la fecha fin sea null me devuelva el valor del campo solicitado en el select o dicho de otra forma que solo considere que el dato de fecha inicio sea menor al valor de application_date y que se consideren los demas criterios.

Lo mejor es no usar `BETWEEN`. De esta manera, puedes tomar esta condición:

```
WHERE IN_APLICATIONDATE BETWEEN FECHA_INICIO AND FECHA_FIN
```

y modificarla para que tome en cuenta la posibilidad de null de esta manera:

```
WHERE IN_APLICATIONDATE >= FECHA_INICIO
AND (FECHA_FIN IS NULL OR IN_APLICATIONDATE <= FECHA_FIN)
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias